# How can statistics on an ad.fly shortened link be fetched programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like my ASP.NET website to be able to work out how much revenue has been generated through certain Ad.fly links over a particular month (or lifetime if month not possible) - how could this be done?

Comment: Visit ad.fly yourself?

Comment: I really need it to be automated; the best thing I can think of so far is to write a program with a built in browser running on some sever that can do the login and call the ad.fly JSON https://adf.ly/publisher/links?sEcho=2&iColumns... url to retrieve data. This is nasty though.